# Java: Need to create PDF from byte-Array

Tags: java

From a DB2 table I've got blob which I'm converting to a byte array so I can work with it. I need to take the byte array and create a `PDF` out of it.

This is what I have:

```
static void byteArrayToFile(byte[] bArray) {  
    try {  
        // Create file  
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.pdf");  
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);  
        for (Byte b: bArray) {  
            out.write(b);  
        }  
        out.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
    }  
}
```

But the `PDF` it creates is not right, it has a bunch of black lines running from top to bottom on it.

I was actually able to create the correct `PDF` by writing a web application using essentially the same process. The primary difference between the web application and the code about was this line:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

So I know the byte array is a `PDF` and it can be done, but my code in `byteArrayToFile` won't create a clean `PDF`.

Any ideas on how I can make it work?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Sending your output through a `FileWriter` is corrupting it because the data is bytes, and `FileWriter`s are for writing characters. All you need is:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf");
out.write(bArray);
out.close();
```

Comment: Hi Jason can you please share me the code or share me some link am also facing the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Anand **bArray** is the byte array.  If u have got the array, then the code provided with the answer is the usable code to convert a byte array to PDF file.

Comment: Hi Jason, I m using same and getting byte array from web service. But even unable to open pdf it is showing "unable to open this file either not a supported file type or file has been damaged". Please help me on this.

Comment: Hi Jason, i have the similar question, unable to open the pdf ... please help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score 7):

One can utilize the autoclosable interface that was introduced in java 7.

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf")) {
   out.write(bArray);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really matters here, but try-with-recourses for autoclosable was introduced in java 7. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Answer (score 1):

Read from file or string to `bytearray`.

```java
byte[] filedata = null;
String content = new String(bytearray);
content = content.replace("\r", "").replace("\uf8ff", "").replace("'", "").replace("\"", "").replace("`", "");
String[] arrOfStr = content.split("\n");
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);
try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
    // setting font family and font size
    cs.beginText(); 
    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 14);
    cs.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
    cs.newLineAtOffset(20, 750);
    for (String str: arrOfStr) {
        cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -15);
        cs.showText(str);
    }
    cs.newLine();
    cs.endText();
}
document.save(znaFile);
document.close();
```

Comment: The answer would benefit from better formatting and an explanation.

Comment: Formatting is not allowing over this site, and formatting eclipse could do by itself I guess so. Anyway this code is tested and running for changing the bytearray to pdf file. One more suggestion, if file needs to be shared over the network, better to use bytearray and use FileUtils library.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String getPDF() throws IOException {

        File file = new File("give complete path of file which must be read");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bytesRead;enter code here
        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        System.out.println("it came back"+baos);
        byte[] buffer1= baos.toByteArray();
        String fileName = "give your filename with location";

        //stream.close();
        
        
         FileOutputStream outputStream =
                    new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         
         outputStream.write(buffer1);
        
         return fileName;
        
    }
```

Comment: hello i have the similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java